# How to use negative criteria with two conditions to subset a data frame in R

Tags: subset

I want to drop rows where both variables are blank.

Nb. They are not populated with NAs, just empty.

I have been trying things like this:

```
subdat <- dat[!(dat$Keyword_2 == "" & dat$Keyword_6 == ""),]
```

but the returned data frame is mostly populated with incorrect NA rows.

I'm sure this is simple, but cannot work this out in R! HELPPP

Comment: Do you want both to be true or for those to be true together? I think you might want `dat[(dat$Keyword_2 != "") & (dat$Keyword_6 != ""),]` or something like that. Be careful with the `(`. One other thing to check is that they are blank `""` and not `"  "`. So stripping out the blank spaces may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help roarkz. I have tried your suggestion and I get a blank dataframe populated with NAs. To clarify I want to subset the dataframe to exclude any rows where both variables are empty, so for those to be true together.